# (JAVA) cut array into statements and save it in objects of a new array?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, contains, cut

I need a program that cuts an 1-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array.
But: the 2nd-dimension must not be annother array, but new objects.

I have two inputs:

- String Array 1 contains a full command-statement (including args and values)
- String Array 2 contains all valid arg-Names

I want one output:

- A String Array which contains the arg+value: All Elements of this Array are objects of the class "cuttedStatement"

These objects of the class "cuttedStatement" can have both:
(Argument + his value) OR (only Argument). So Argument with or without value are valid!

Look at the describing picture:
[image]

Here is my code for the CutterPrgm:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] statement = {"-in", "FILENAME", "-out", "FILENAME" , "-keep" , "-typ", ".avi", "-status"};
        String[] validArgs = {"-in", "-out", "-keep", "-typ", "-status"};

        ArrayList<CuttedStatement> cuttedOutputList = new ArrayList<>();


            for (int i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
                boolean contains = Arrays.asList(validArgs).contains(statement[i+1]);
                if(contains) {
                    CuttedStatement obj[i] = new CuttedStatement(statement[i]);
                    cuttedOutputList.add(obj);
                }else {
                    CuttedStatement obj[i] = new CuttedStatement(statement[i],statement[i+1]);
                    cuttedOutputList.add(obj);
                }
            }

    }

}
```

this is my CuttedStatement-class:

```
public class CuttedStatement {

    String argument;
    String value;
    boolean hasValue;

    public CuttedStatement(String argument) {
        this.argument = argument;
        this.hasValue = false;
    }

    public CuttedStatement(String argument, String value) {
        this.argument = argument;
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }
}
```

So now my question: As you might guess, the program doesn't work.

My first Problem is the "obj[i]" object. I wanted to create a new "obj" with index=i every new iteration so that you have: Array = {obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, etc...}. This looks not to work.

Maybe you know a solution for me or have some tips. I hope so. Thank you very much for help, every help is welcome!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] statement = {"-in", "FILENAME", "-out", "FILENAME", "-keep", "-typ", ".avi", "-status"};
        String[] validArgs = {"-in", "-out", "-keep", "-typ", "-status"};

        ArrayList<CutStatement> cuttedOutputList = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
            // do not use Arrays.asList() here. It will create a List instance in each iteration
            // not sure that stream is the best solution though
            int i_temp = i; // for lambda in stream
            boolean contains = true;
            if (i != statement.length - 1) { // if it is not the last element
                contains = Arrays.stream(validArgs).anyMatch(s -> s.equals(statement[i_temp + 1]));
            }
            if (contains) {
                // just do not use `[i]` here
                CutStatement obj = new CutStatement(statement[i]);
                cuttedOutputList.add(obj);
            } else {
                CutStatement obj = new CutStatement(statement[i], statement[i + 1]);
                cuttedOutputList.add(obj);
                i++; // increase i because we added two values from `statement`
            }
        }
        System.out.println(cuttedOutputList);
    }

}

class CutStatement {
    private String argument;
    private String value;
    private boolean hasValue;

    public CutStatement(String argument) {
        this.argument = argument;
        this.hasValue = false;
    }

    public CutStatement(String argument, String value) {
        this.argument = argument;
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (hasValue) {
            return "(" + argument + " = " + value + ")";
        } else {
            return "(" + argument + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

This program outputs
[(-in = FILENAME), (-out = FILENAME), (-keep), (-typ = .avi), (-status)]

Answer (score 0):

I have little modified your logic. Here Map will contain what u require. Play with map for your final output.

```
String[] statement = { "-in", "FILENAME", "-out", "FILENAME", "-keep", "-typ", ".avi", "-status" };
        String[] validArgs = { "-in", "-out", "-keep", "-typ", "-status" };
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String key = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < statement.length; i++) {
            boolean contains = false;
            if(i + 1<statement.length){
                contains = Arrays.asList(validArgs).contains(statement[i + 1]);
            }
            if (contains) {
                m.put(key, statement[i]);
            } else {
                key = statement[i];
                m.put(key, "");
            }
        }
```